# Customized Date Sorting is not working when we click on grid column i.e on grid column click

Tags: extjs

On boarding of the grid the date column is not sorted so I have written `sorterFn()` called as customized sorting and it works as expected. But when we click on grid column on sort change then grid dates are not getting sorted out.

I have tried by writing `sortChange()` by looking into the `ExtJS Docx [ Ext.grid.header.Container and Ext.grid.Panel]` event in the grid listener, but `sortChange()` event itself is not called.

Here is the sample code I have written for on load which is working as expected.

```
updateGrid: function(filter) {
    me.store.load();
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(me.getStore().sorters)){
        me.getStore().sorters.clear();
    }

    me.getStore().setSorters([{
        sorterProperty: "CALENDAR_DATE",
        direction: "ASC",
        sorterFn: function (date1, date2) {
            var d1, d2;
            if(me.filterDef.mvValues.filter.frequencyFilter == 
                        DCRDashboardConstants.frequency['Daily']){
                d1 = new Date(date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE).getTime();
                d2 = new Date(date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE).getTime();
            } else if(me.filterDef.mvValues.filter.frequencyFilter == 
                     DCRDashboardConstants.frequency['Weekly']){
                d1 = new Date(date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE.split('-') 
                      [0]).getTime();
                d2 = new Date(date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE.split('-') 
                      [0]).getTime();
                } else {
                    d1 = date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE;
                    d2 = date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE;
                }

                return (d1 > d2) ? 1 : (d1 === d2 ? 0 : -1);
            }
    }]);
}
```

As `sorterFn: function (date1, date2) {}`will be called only one time (on grid loading), I have written this code in the listener given below but the problem is the even itself is not called by extjs.

```
listeners: {
  storeBeforeLoad: function(store) {
  },
  if(!Ext.isEmpty(me.getStore().sorters)){
        me.getStore().sorters.clear();
    }

    me.getStore().setSorters([{
        sorterProperty: "CALENDAR_DATE",
        direction: "ASC",
        sorterFn: function (date1, date2) {
            var d1, d2;
            if(me.filterDef.mvValues.filter.frequencyFilter == 
                        DCRDashboardConstants.frequency['Daily']){
                d1 = new Date(date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE).getTime();
                d2 = new Date(date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE).getTime();
            } else if(me.filterDef.mvValues.filter.frequencyFilter == 
                     DCRDashboardConstants.frequency['Weekly']){
                d1 = new Date(date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE.split('-') 
                      [0]).getTime();
                d2 = new Date(date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE.split('-') 
                      [0]).getTime();
                } else {
                    d1 = date1.data.CALENDAR_DATE;
                    d2 = date2.data.CALENDAR_DATE;
                }

                return (d1 > d2) ? 1 : (d1 === d2 ? 0 : -1);
            }
    }]);
  }
```

This event is not called by ExtJS. Could you please help me out to sort the dates on sort change of grid column.

Answer (score 0):

There's no code inside the listener `storeBeforeLoad` if you want to load this function when the store load you can try this

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    //rest of configs of your store
    listeners: {
        load: {
            fn: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
                //function here
            }

        },
        beforeload: {
            fn: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
                // other function here
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.
I am able to sort while on loading of the grid. I am facing the issue whenever i have clicked on specific column (Ex: date column) after loading then i am unable to sort the date column. Reason for this is me.getStore().setSorters([{ }]) has been called only on boarding of the application only not when we click on specific grid column. So now i am looking for to sort on clicking of the column.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `sorter` in `grid columns` like:

```
sorter: {
    sorterFn: 'sorterMethodName'
}
```

Documentation:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-sorter

Comment: Sure, i will try this if available in 6.0.2 and let you know.
Thank for your help :).